# What is the current status of handwriting recognition on the iPad with an air pencil or stylus

Tags: ios, ipad, handwriting

Ideally I want to be able to use my ipad as a clipboard running google sheets to do inventory entry.  So I'm looking for a general purpose stylus to text converter.

Seems strange that Palm got this pretty close to right 20 years ago, but there is little progress since.

Research into this found a flurry of articles written shortly after the air pencil came out, but I've found little since then.  So my current answer is, "Moribund"

Comment: You ought to update your question here with the specific model of iPad you own, as there are tremendous differences in capabilities between models.

Comment: @da7 None of the current models support handwriting for Google Sheets or similar.

Answer (score 3):

iOS currently doesn't support handwriting recognition on OS level. There are apps for the Pro models (with Apple Pencil) that recognize handwriting, but this won't help you with Google Sheets or similar.

Things appear to be more bright with iOS 14 (the version to be released later in 2020). Apple will introduce handwriting recognition on OS level, at least for the Pro models, with a feature called Scribble. Check out https://www.apple.com/ipados/ipados-preview/ for the details already known.

[image]

Comment: I am curious if it should be inferred that the hand writing recognition is limited to Pro models? What about iPad with support for 1st gen Apple Pencil that would support running iPadOS 14?

Comment: @NimeshNeema see https://twitter.com/RobertPHuff/status/1275847036840153089, at least in the current beta it works with all Apple Pencil

Answer (score 1):

One way is use the Mazec key board app http://www.product.metamoji.com/en/mazec/

It sort of works with normal handwriting but i think I think -Palm Pilot recognition was better

Mazec suggested the last  part after the hyphen so some things have improved

the app provides an area to write in that replaces the keyboard